# How to put element in middle of rounded corner?

Tags: css

[image]

I have an element (the gray one) 120px/120px with 50% border-radius, I want to put another element (the orange one) in the middle of the top left border. How can I do this ?

**Here is my Code:**

```
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
```

but the element only moves around it's center.

## EDIT

Working sample : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a424das/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by using some maths:

1. put the element in `top=0 ; left:50%;`
2. translateX by `x = - (height/2 * cos(45deg)) = -60 * 0.707 = -42px`
3. translateY by `y = height/2 * (1 - sin(45deg)) = 60*(1 - 0.707) = 18px`
4. translateX and translateY by -50% to center;

`transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateX(-42px) translateY(18px);`

## Edit

For the solution to be responsive (if the big circle is 40vh/40vh):

`transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateX(calc(-40vh/2 * 0.707)) translateY(calc(40vh/2 * 0.3));`

Here is a working example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf4L6pao/4/)

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.big-circle {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.small-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateX(calc(-40vh/2 * 0.707)) translateY(calc(40vh/2 * 0.3));
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle">
  12
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Updated based on a comment*

You can do like this, using a wrapper that you rotate, which will be responsive as well

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.big-circle, .small-circle {
  position: relative;  
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.small-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.small-circle div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top: calc(50% - (30px / 2));
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);      /*  this will reverse the rotation/content  */
}
.big-circle-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  line-height: 40vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle">
    <div>123</div>
  </div>
  <div class="big-circle-content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<strike>You can do like this, using a pseudo, which will be responsive as well</strike>

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf4L6pao/1/)

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.big-circle, .small-circle {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;  
}
.small-circle {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.big-circle:nth-child(2) .small-circle {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.small-circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top: calc(50% - (30px / 2));
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle">  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle">  
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the `big-circle` is not going to contain other elements, you can drop the `small-circle` element and set the pseudo and the `rotate` on the `big-circle`

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.big-circle {
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;  
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.big-circle:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.big-circle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top: calc(50% - (30px / 2));
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
</div>

<div class="big-circle">
</div>
```

Comment: I my case, both circles have content. This solution does not work for me.

Comment: @MohamedRamrami If you post _all_ your requirements in your question we will be able to suggest a good solution, and if one have content inside it is very simple to reverse the rotate so it will look how it is suppose to

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Updated my answer showing _how-to_ when both circles has content ... and still responsive

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated my answer to be responsive without additional markup and css. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your code with this:

**UPDATED:**

```
.small-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top:12%;
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Does not give the desired result.

Comment: You want what it shows in your question,Right? Sorry, I just saw top, was top-left. See the updated version of the above code.

Comment: Yeah, but how did you find these values `top:12%; left: 20%;` ? 
I managed to make it work see my answer above.

Comment: ooo, Nice work. But if you can do the same thing in 8 lines of code why to give 3 more extra lines to increase complexity.
How i get? Place some value and check it regularly if it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.big-circle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.small-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: coral;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  //transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="big-circle">
  <div class="small-circle">
  
  </div>
</div>
```